# How can i make this Complex query for SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

### I have a database that looks like this:

Player (**UserId**, Mail, Password, Username, LastLogin)

Leaderboard (**UserId***, Level, Kills, Deaths)

Match (**MatchId**, **HostId***, ServerIp, StartTime, Team1Points, Team2Points)

MatchStats (**UserId***, **MatchId***, Kills, Deaths)

Weapons (**IdWeapon**, Name, Damage, FireRate, ReloadTime, Range)

Inventory(**UserId***, **WeaponType***, Skin)

---

I need a query that selects the LastLogin of every Player that is dead more than 12 times (MatchStats.Deaths > 12) in at least 3 matches.
Can someone help me? I'm having troubles with possibles Joins or Subqueries.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT LastLogin FROM Player WHERE UserId=(SELECT UserId FROM (SELECT * FROM MatchStats WHERE Deaths>12 AS TAB) WHERE COUNT(UserId)>3))
```

or

```
SELECT LastLogin FROM Player
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(SELECT Count(*) FROM MatchStats WHERE Deaths>12 GROUP BY UserId)>3 GROUP BY UserId;
```

But i feel i'm quite far from having the corret query, maybe I'm missing a Join or maybe I'm doing it totally wrong..

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: @Akina I tried something like this :
`SELECT LastLogin FROM Player
WHERE UserId=(SELECT UserId
     FROM (SELECT * FROM MatchStats 
                  WHERE Deaths>12 AS TAB) 
                            WHERE COUNT(UserId)>3))`
But i feel i'm quite far from having the corret query, maybe I'm missing a Join, idk...

Comment: @gNt edit your question and add your effort to reopen the question.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I edited it, its still closed

Comment: @gNt I have voted it for reopen. Hope it would be opened soon. Meanwhile you can try tis solution:  select lastlogin from Player p
where exists
(
      select UserIdfrom MatchStats m 
      where deaths>=12 and p.UserId=m.UserId
      group by userid 
      having count(distinct matchid)>=3
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` to check whether a player have 12 death in at least three matches

```
select lastlogin from Player p 
where exists 
(  select UserIdfrom MatchStats m 
   where deaths>=12 and p.UserId=m.UserId 
   group by userid 
   having count(distinct matchid)>=3 
)
```